# Htaccess code for laravel not using public path

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, plesk, laravel-6

I know this is a very popular question but I haven't been able to find a working solution for Laravel 6. I am using windows Plesk to setup the Laravel project.

I don't want to set my document root to the public folder.

I've tried the .htaccess mod_rewrite method

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and also this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there a decent method of removing 'public' in a development environment that:Works with L6

Thanks

Comment: What happens exactly with these attempts? (Is `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite enabled?) Both these methods should "work" (they are essentially the same as far as rewriting goes), assuming this `.htaccess` file is in the document root and you have the standard Laravel access file in the `/public` subdirectory. "that:Works with L6" - Incidentally, as far as `.htaccess` goes, it's exactly the same method regardless of application... Laravel, WordPress, Joomla, anything where you are "hiding" a subdirectory.